# close multiple nested Material UI dialogs with browser back button - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

i want to toggle a material ui Dialog visibility base on URL. for example when URL is somthing like this
`site.com/#UKLMCBUWPO` modal one be visible and when `site.com/#UKLMCBUWPO&KLMCnhjmWPO`
modal two be visible and each time user click the browser back button last state in url pops and the second modal be hidden and so on.
basically user can interact with browser back and forward buttons to show and hide the dialog.
i just want some gibberish text in URL when modals open and the gibrish removed when they closed until no modals are shown on the page.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) to configure the router and `props.location.hash` to get hash link and split it and get the last item in the array.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-multiple-modal-display-kwvlk?file=/src/App.js)

**Navs**

```js
     <Link
        className={
          "tab " + currentRoute.includes("about") ? "tab active" : "tab"
        }
        to="/modal#state=KLMCnhjmWPO"
      >
        Go to Modal 1
      </Link>
      <Link
        className={
          "tab " + currentRoute.includes("contact") ? "tab active" : "tab"
        }
        to={{
          pathname: "/modal",
          hash: "#state=KLMCnhjmWPO&#state=UKLMCBUWPO"
        }}
      >
        Go to Modal 2
      </Link>
```

**Routes**

```js
<HashRouter>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/modal" exact component={Modal} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
```

**Sample Modal**

```js
const Modal = props => {
  const lastModal = props.location.hash.split("&");
  return <div>Modal - {lastModal[lastModal.length - 1]}</div>;
};
```